# Getting the content of a variable outside the submit function event

Tags: jquery

This is my 3rd question so please understand :).

I have this submit function - nothing fancy, just a serializeArray() and some retrieved values:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){

    var formdata = $(this).serializeArray();
    var values = {};

    $.each(formdata, function(i, field){
        values[field.name] = field.value
    });

    var id = values["mrmid"];


});
```

**How can I pass the id variable outside the submit function event so I can write the content of the variable id on this div?**

```
$("#results").html(id);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to pass the value of "id" outside of the submit function?  Where would you pass that value to? To another function?  Or do you just want to show the value of "id" right away?

Comment: Its a simple script which will generate custom links. The user pastes the info into the form and on the submit click, the links are generated on a div which is under the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `id` to be a **global variable**:

```
var id;

$("#myform").submit(function(){

    var formdata = $(this).serializeArray();
    var values = {};

    $.each(formdata, function(i, field){
        values[field.name] = field.value
    });

    id = values["mrmid"];


});


$("#results").html(id);
```

Comment: Or pass that id into another function (if there is one), which handles the html injection.

Comment: Really, will it work? let me check.. if I have multiple values and lets say id is a sum between the values of several vars, do I need to declare each one globally?

Comment: I think the second way is better, could you show me an example? how to pass it in another function i mean...

Comment: You can make 'values' as global variable if you want to have more than one id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){

    var formdata = $(this).serializeArray();
    var values = {};

    $.each(formdata, function(i, field){
        values[field.name] = field.value
    });

    var id = values["mrmid"];

    $("#results").html(id);

});
```

I guess I don't understand. It's pretty much that easy.

Comment: If i do it like this, after the submit, the value disappears

Comment: Well what Curt says is fine, define the variable outside the function first, then just change the value of it inside the submit. I would stray from global variables if at all possible though, just bad practice, but there are times when it makes sense.

Comment: Bull! We need to see all your code, because you had to have done it wrong. It does work. Make sure you remove the `var` declaration inside your submit function.